# ¿Por qué no puedo asignar el valor de una variable como clave de un array en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tomando varios valores de elementos del DOM, guardándolos en variables para luego crear un array y pasarlo al servidor mediante Ajax.

Son varios elementos y varias posibilidades que voy evaluando en un bloque `switch ... case`.  Mi idea a asignar valores a algunas variables dentro de cada `case` y al final crear el array con los datos que voy a enviar al servidor, así me ahorro tiempo y varias líneas de código.

Pero me doy cuenta de que no puedo hacerlo.

Ejemplo:

```
       /*Variable para enviar al servidor*/
        var arrData;

        /*Variables que cambian según el case*/
        var strCampo;
        var strTabla;
        var intIdElemento;
        var arrParams;

        /*Variables fijas*/
        var strElemento = $("#cbxUtilitarios").val();
        var intIdLiturgia = $("#ibxLiturgia").val();

        switch (strElemento) {

        case "id_himno":

            intIdElemento = $("#cbxHimnos").val();
            strTabla = 'liturgia_horas_himnos_join';
            strCampo='id_himno';
            break;

        case "id_antifona":

            intIdElemento = $("#cbxAntifona").val();
            strTabla = 'liturgia_horas_antifonas_join';
            strCampo='id_antifona';
            break;

        default:
        break;
        }

        /*Recogemos lo que ocurrió en los case y lo posteamos*/
        arrParams = {'id_liturgia':intIdLiturgia, strElemento:intIdElemento};
        var arrAction = {'insert': strTabla};
        arrData = {arrAction,arrParams};
        post_data(arrData);
```

El resultado deseado para el segundo case por ejemplo sería este:

```
{
    arrAction: {insert: "liturgia_horas_antifonas_join"}, 
    arrParams: {id_liturgia: "0901092901", id_antifona: "58"}
}
```

Sin embargo, estoy obteniendo esto:

```
{
    arrAction: {insert: "liturgia_horas_antifonas_join"}, 
    arrParams: {id_liturgia: "0901092901", strElemento: "58"}
}
```

**¿Por qué no me reconoce la clave equivalente a `strElemento`?**

Comment: tienes que asignarlo como si fuese un array. var arrParams = {}; arrParams[id_liturgia] = intidElemento; arrParams[strElemento] = intidElemento

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tal como lo tienes no puede funcionar porqué estás asignando `strElemento` como si fuera un key del objeto.

Solución:

```js
var strElemento = 'id_antifona';
var intIdLiturgia = 0901092901;
        
arrParams = {'id_liturgia':intIdLiturgia };
arrParams[strElemento] = 58; // Crear key y pasar el valor

console.log(arrParams);
```

Comment: ¡Vaya! entonces era cuestión de ponerlo entre **`[`** y **`]`** ¿Hay algún motivo por el cual funcione de esa manera? Lo he usado como indica @dddenis, en una sola línea: `arrParams = {'id_liturgia': intIdLiturgia, [strElemento]: intIdElemento};`, aunque marcaré esta como solución por tener una explicación más precisa y prueba de concepto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano - Funciona por que es lo mismo :) la única diferencia que veo es que esta respuesta puede ser en su momento más flexible porque podrías asignarlo en otro momento y/o asignar otras claves `key` _on the fly_...

Comment: Me refería a por qué hay que ponerlo entre `[]` @aldanux.

Comment: @A.Cedano - Si a eso me refiero: _Funciona por que es lo mismo_ ... Es la sintaxis para crear una clave en un objeto _inline_ (para decirlo de una manera) ... voy a mirar si encuentro una documentación sobre eso...

Comment: @aldanux He editado mi respuesta y he añadido la documentación.

Comment: @dddenis - Perfecto... :) +1

Answer (score 8):

Para que interpreta tu variable strElemento como clave de tu objeto debes de encerrarla entre llaves.

```
arrParams = {'id_liturgia': intIdLiturgia, [strElemento]: intIdElemento};
```

> Fuente: [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Answer (score 3):

Lo que indicas antes de los dos puntos es el nombre de la propiedad, utilices comillas o no.

Para crear una propiedad con nombre dinámico deberías utilizar la sintaxis con corchetes:

```js
// Lo que indicas es el nombre de la propiedad
// Sea con comillas o sin comillas
var foo = {
  prop1: 4,
  'prop2': 4
};

console.log(foo);


var strElemento = 'nombrePropiedad';

// Así creas una propiedad de nombre strElemento
foo = {
  strElemento: 4
};

console.log(foo);

// Si quieres crear la propiedad con el valor de la variable como nombre
// debes utilizar la sintaxis con corchetes
foo = {};
foo[strElemento] = 4;

console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Con:

```
arrParams = {'id_liturgia':intIdLiturgia, strElemento:intIdElemento};
```

estás creando dos posiciones: `id_liturgia` y `strElemento`.
Para que la variable `strElemento` te cree una clave en el objeto, se puede hacer así:

```
arrParams = {'id_liturgia':intLiturgia}
arrParams[strElemento] = intIdElemento;
```